# exponentialRampToValueAtTime does not prevent cracking in firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox, html5-audio

When I play a tone and then stop it, unpleasant "crack" is heard and the beginning and the end. I searched for a solution and found out that reducing the volume over time should solve that issue.

Therefore, I use `AudioGainMode` to ramp up and down, instead of cutting the audio abruptly:

```
controlGain.gain.exponentialRampToValueAtTime(
    1,
    gAudioCtx.currentTime+time_milliseconds/1000
 );
// and later...
controlGain.gain.exponentialRampToValueAtTime(
    0.0001,
    gAudioCtx.currentTime+time_milliseconds/1000
 );
```

Because exponential functions are not defined at `0`, `0.0001` is used instead.

However, in Firefox, I can still hear nasty cracking. I also noticed that using longer delays has no effect - the gain reaches target value instantly.

```js
function sleep(ms) {
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        setTimeout(resolve, ms);
    });
}
function play() {
const AUDIO_RAMP_DELAY = 50;


var gAudioCtx = new AudioContext();
const controlGain = gAudioCtx.createGain();
controlGain.gain.value = 0.00001;
/// Full volume at t+50ms
controlGain.gain.exponentialRampToValueAtTime(
    1,
    gAudioCtx.currentTime+AUDIO_RAMP_DELAY/1000
 );
controlGain.connect(gAudioCtx.destination);

var osc = gAudioCtx.createOscillator();


// create a tone around 440hz
const length = 1024;
var real = new Float32Array(length);
var imag = new Float32Array(length);
real[440]=1;
//real[512]=1;
var wave = gAudioCtx.createPeriodicWave(real, imag, {disableNormalization: true});
osc.frequency.value = 1;
osc.setPeriodicWave(wave);
osc.connect(controlGain);
osc.start();

(async function() {
    await sleep(AUDIO_RAMP_DELAY+1);
    // now we're at full volume, wait another 2 seconds
    await sleep(2000);
    controlGain.gain.exponentialRampToValueAtTime(
        0.00001,
        gAudioCtx.currentTime+50/1000
    );
    await sleep(2000);
    osc.stop();
    document.querySelector("button").disabled = false;
})();
}
```

```html
<h2>Warning: this demo makes loud sounds!</h2>
<button onclick="play(); this.disabled=true">Click to play</button>
```

How to make it work in firefox as well?

Answer (score 1):

I noticed too that the `exponentialRampToValueAtTime()` does not seem to work as intended in Firefox. Too me it seems like an incorrect implementation.

A workaround could be to use [`linearRampToValueAtTime`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AudioParam/linearRampToValueAtTime) instead.

Alternatively you could also use [`setValueCurveAtTime`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AudioParam/setValueCurveAtTime) to define your own curve.